# Writing library for Twitter, where am I going wrong?

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm writing a library to connect to Twitter that uses [Requests for PHP](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/). I'm not sure, but I don't think that I'm building the OAuth correctly because I can't authenticate. I've double-checked it, and checked it against another existing library but still can't seem to get it right.

The code is [here](https://raw.github.com/hassankhan/resyted-backend-php/master/library/Resyted/Service/OAuth1AService.php).

The idea is you instantiate the service, send it config parameters, and before it does the request, it generates the `'Authorization: OAuth xxx'` header and adds it to said request.

```
$twitter = array(
    'consumer_key'        => '',
    'consumer_secret'     => '',
    'access_token'        => '',
    'access_token_secret' => '',
    'screen_name'         => '_hassankhan',
    'api_url'             => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/'
);

$service = new OAuth1AService('Twitter', $twitter['api_url']);
$service->config($twitter);
$service->doGet(
    'statuses/user_timeline.json',
    array(
        'screen_name'      => '_hassankhan',
        'include_entities' => 'true'
    ),
    array(),
    'raw'
);
print($service->getResult());
```

Comment: any error messages also have you created a twitter app on their platform and got the keys for the api calls?

Comment: Yes, I've created a Twitter app, obviously. The response I receive from Twitter's servers are response code is 401, and the message is ``{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}``

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend you to use one of the already made libraries like tmhOAuth which make it really easy to interact with the twitter api.

---

As for your problem, seems you don't sign your request correctly. At least I could not easily find out if you include all request parameters to create the signature.

> The oauth_signature parameter contains a value which is generated by
>   running all of the other request parameters and two secret values
>   through a signing algorithm.

Creating the signature is described in this document: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature .